# Getting Values with MongoDB regex

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

How to get Values of `opts` in a String  with MongoDB regex?
I want to search cats `name` And get cats `opts` with regex

**Schema:**

```
const childSchema = new Schema({
    type: String,
    id: { type: Number, required: true, unique: true },
    title: String,
    message_text: String,
    parse_mode: String,
    thumb_url: String,
    description: String,
});

const parentSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Number,
    name: String,
    opts: childSchema,
});
```

**Code:**

```
Mq.aggregate(
    [
        {
            "$match": {
                "name": { "$regex": "c", "$options": "i" }
            }
        },
        { "$unwind": "$name" },
        {
            "$match": {
                "name": { "$regex": "c", "$options": "i" }
            }
        },
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$opts",
            }
        }
    ],
    function (err, results) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log(results)
        }
    }
)
```

**Output:**

```
[ { _id:
     { type: 'article',
       id: 2,
       title: 'persian cat',
       message_text: 'test',
       parse_mode: 'Markdown',
       thumb_url: 'http://www.immig-chicago.com/clientuploads/graphics/dvLottery_2a.jpg',
       description: 'des',
       _id: 5a011c3236bdcc2540747d0f } },
  { _id:
     { type: 'article',
       id: 1,
       title: 'cat',
       message_text: 'Hi',
       parse_mode: 'Markdown',
       thumb_url: 'http://www.immig-chicago.com/clientuploads/graphics/dvLottery_2a.jpg',
       description: 'des',
       _id: 59f7cf23ba668128fc48b8a7 } } ]
```

**But I need values inside of opts in output, I Mean Something like This:**

```
{ type: 'article',
       id: 2,
       title: 'persian cat',
       message_text: 'test',
       parse_mode: 'Markdown',
       thumb_url: 'http://www.immig-chicago.com/clientuploads/graphics/dvLottery_2a.jpg',
       description: 'des',
       _id: 5a011c3236bdcc2540747d0f },
{ type: 'article',
       id: 1,
       title: 'cat',
       message_text: 'Hi',
       parse_mode: 'Markdown',
       thumb_url: 'http://www.immig-chicago.com/clientuploads/graphics/dvLottery_2a.jpg',
       description: 'des',
       _id: 59f7cf23ba668128fc48b8a7 }
```

**Update:**
I have `let opts = [];` in my Project and I want to remove the key and just get values of opts and put them in `let opts - [{},{},{},....]`

**My Data:**

```
   [ [ { _id: 0, name: 'dog', opts: [Object], __v: 0 },
        { _id: 1, name: 'cat', opts: [Object], __v: 0 },
        { _id: 2, name: 'persian cat', opts: [Object], __v: 0 } ] ]
```

Comment: Why are you doing `{ "$unwind": "$name" }` when `"name"` is not an array? I think you mean `{ "$unwind": "$opts" }`. Presuming `Mq` actually relates to `parentSchema` here, but the  different naming everywhere is not really helping.

Comment: oh okey, I have `name` and `opts` and I want to search cats name in `name` and get opts of cats in output

Comment: So?? My point is `{ "$unwind": "$name" }` should be throwing a **very loud error** since it is not an array itself. Either that or your question is misleading and your actual data is completely different to how you present it here. So you have not really "cleared up" anything that was just asked of you.

Comment: I haven't any error in my output! When I used `{ "$unwind": "$name" },`, But I removed That Line. Notice: name is string and is my cats names, I want to get cats opts in output

Comment: Can't see how you still don't understand this does not make any sense. I think I've been pretty clear on the relevant points. Your query and presented data "do not match up". So unless they do, it's really unclear what you are even asking here.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English, I will Update my question with a photo after 15 min to clarification

Comment: Please DO NOT POST PHOTOS OR IMAGES. TEXT is perfectly fine. It's just that you appear to be showing the WRONG THINGS. If you need help with phrasing your question or understanding these comments then try to find someone with better english to assist you. But posting images is really not necessary and more often than not obscures the real question even more. Simply show a sample of your "real data" ( as TEXT ) and the result you expect to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved ✔️

1: I Finded My Cats `name` with regex
2: I Got Cats opts value By `.distinct()`

```
var regex = new RegExp("c", "i"); //Case insensitive Match
Mq.find().distinct('opts', {name: regex}, function(err, docs) {
    console.log(docs)
})
```

**Output:**

```
    [{ type: 'article',
           id: 1,
           title: 'cat',
           message_text: 'Hi',
           parse_mode: 'Markdown',
           thumb_url: 'http://www.immig-chicago.com/clientuploads/graphics/dvLottery_2a.jpg',
           description: 'des',
           _id: 59f7cf23ba668128fc48b8a7 },
{ type: 'article',
           id: 2,
           title: 'persian cat',
           message_text: 'test',
           parse_mode: 'Markdown',
           thumb_url: 'http://www.immig-chicago.com/clientuploads/graphics/dvLottery_2a.jpg',
           description: 'des',
           _id: 5a011c3236bdcc2540747d0f } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I know one thing for sure You can use [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) on you `Mq.aggregate` to hide the `_id` on the final result by assigning the value like this: `{ _id: 0 }`.

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27725509/remove-id-from-mongoose-aggregate-response) that might help ;)

Comment: When I Added `{ $project: {_id: 0} },` I Got  `[ {}, {} ]`

Comment: nope...definitely not like that. I only mentioned it there on how to use after the _id: 0 you should specify all the other fields that you want to be projected like in the example in the link  { $project: {_id: 0, name: '$_id.name', city: '$_id.city', state: '$_id.state'} } . if you can't manage before me after a little I will try to bring the full example on my pc and debug your code